# How to use subsets when load balancing between app versions with istio?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, istio

I have the following service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: downstream-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: downstream
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

which I'd like to load balance based on app version which I've defined as follows in deployments:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: downstream-deployment-v1
  labels:
    app: downstream
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: downstream
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: downstream
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: downstream
        image: downstream:0.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: downstream-deployment-v2
  labels:
    app: downstream
    version: v2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: downstream
      version: v2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: downstream
        version: v2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: downstream
        image: downstream:0.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Now this routes traffic 50/50 as expected on both of those deployments but I'd like to tweak the weights as per https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPRouteDestination so I've defined `DestinationRule` and `VirtualService`:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: downstream-destination
spec:
  host: downstream-service.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: downstream-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
  - downstream-service.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - name: "downstream-service-v1-routes"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: downstream-service.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v1
      weight: 5
  - name: "downstream-service-v2-routes"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: downstream-service.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v2
      weight: 95
```

but with this I'm still getting 50/50 split.

I've tried replacing `downstream-service.svc.cluster.local` with just `downstream-service` but the result was that without `weight`s defined in the yaml and with `subset`s removed I'd get a 50/50 split but when I've added the subset (without the weights) I'd get all the traffic on the `v1` instance.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

**EDIT**

This might be the cause but I'm not sure what to make of it:

```
$ istioctl x describe service downstream-service
Service: downstream-service
   Port:  80/auto-detect targets pod port 80
DestinationRule: downstream-service for "downstream-service"
   Matching subsets: v1,v2
   No Traffic Policy
VirtualService: downstream-route
   2 HTTP route(s)
$ istioctl x describe pod downstream-deployment-v2-69bdfc8fbf-bm22f
Pod: downstream-deployment-v2-69bdfc8fbf-bm22f
   Pod Ports: 80 (downstream), 15090 (istio-proxy)
--------------------
Service: downstream-service
   Port:  80/auto-detect targets pod port 80
DestinationRule: downstream-service for "downstream-service"
   Matching subsets: v2
      (Non-matching subsets v1)
   No Traffic Policy
VirtualService: downstream-route
   1 additional destination(s) that will not reach this pod
      Route to non-matching subset v1 for (everything)
$ istioctl x describe pod downstream-deployment-v1-65bd866c47-66p9k
Pod: downstream-deployment-v1-65bd866c47-66p9k
   Pod Ports: 80 (downstream), 15090 (istio-proxy)
--------------------
Service: downstream-service
   Port:  80/auto-detect targets pod port 80
DestinationRule: downstream-service for "downstream-service"
   Matching subsets: v1
      (Non-matching subsets v2)
   No Traffic Policy
VirtualService: downstream-route
   1 additional destination(s) that will not reach this pod
      Route to non-matching subset v2 for (everything)
```

**EDIT2**

So I've launched kiali just to see that:

[image]

> The weight is assumed to be 100 because there is only one route destination

https://kiali.io/documentation/v1.13/validations/#_the_weight_is_assumed_to_be_100_because_there_is_only_one_route_destination

Not sure how to fix this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it seems I've missed one big "typo" on my part which was the fact that it's the `routes` that have many `destination`s which are weighted not the `http` that has many weighted `route`s.

So the correct version of my `VirtualService` is as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: downstream-service
spec:
  hosts:
  - downstream-service
  http:
  - name: "downstream-service-routes"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: downstream-service
        subset: v1
      weight: 10
    - destination:
        host: downstream-service
        subset: v2
      weight: 90
```